# How do I implement a callback in PHP?

Tags: php

How are callbacks written in PHP?

Comment: Gonna link another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly) to this one, because I was trying to call a closure.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The manual uses the terms "callback" and "callable" interchangeably, however, "callback" traditionally refers to a string or array value that acts like a [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), referencing a function or class method for future invocation. This has allowed some elements of functional programming since PHP 4. The flavors are:

```
$cb1 = 'someGlobalFunction';
$cb2 = ['ClassName', 'someStaticMethod'];
$cb3 = [$object, 'somePublicMethod'];

// this syntax is callable since PHP 5.2.3 but a string containing it
// cannot be called directly
$cb2 = 'ClassName::someStaticMethod';
$cb2(); // fatal error

// legacy syntax for PHP 4
$cb3 = array(&$object, 'somePublicMethod');
```

This is a safe way to use callable values in general:

```
if (is_callable($cb2)) {
    // Autoloading will be invoked to load the class "ClassName" if it's not
    // yet defined, and PHP will check that the class has a method
    // "someStaticMethod". Note that is_callable() will NOT verify that the
    // method can safely be executed in static context.

    $returnValue = call_user_func($cb2, $arg1, $arg2);
}
```

Modern PHP versions allow the first three formats above to be invoked directly as `$cb()`. `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array` support all the above.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Notes/Caveats:

1. If the function/class is namespaced, the string must contain the fully-qualified name. E.g. `['Vendor\Package\Foo', 'method']`
2. `call_user_func` does not support passing non-objects by reference, so you can either use `call_user_func_array` or, in later PHP versions, save the callback to a var and use the direct syntax: `$cb()`;
3. Objects with an [`__invoke()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) method (including anonymous functions) fall under the category "callable" and can be used the same way, but I personally don't associate these with the legacy "callback" term.
4. The legacy `create_function()` creates a global function and returns its name. It's a wrapper for `eval()` and anonymous functions should be used instead.

Comment: Indeed, using the function is the proper way to do it. While using a variable and then just calling it, as suggested in the accepted answer is cool, it's ugly and won't scale well with code.

Comment: Changed accepted answer. Agreed with comments, this is a great answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to readers coming from Python programming to point out in the answer that `'someGlobalFunction'` indeed is a defined function.

Comment: As of PHP 5.3, there are closures, see [Bart van Heukelom's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2523807/1504300). It's much simpler and "standard" than all this legacy mess.

Comment: Yes, I mention anonymous functions in my answer, but the OP asked for "callback" (in 2008) and these older-style callbacks are still very much in use in tons of PHP codebases.

Answer (score 86):

With PHP 5.3, you can now do this:

```
function doIt($callback) { $callback(); }

doIt(function() {
    // this will be done
});
```

Finally a nice way to do it. A great addition to PHP, because callbacks are awesome.

Comment: This needs to be the top answer.

Answer (score 31):

Implementation of a callback is done like so

```
// This function uses a callback function. 
function doIt($callback) 
{ 
    $data = "this is my data";
    $callback($data); 
} 


// This is a sample callback function for doIt(). 
function myCallback($data) 
{ 
    print 'Data is: ' .  $data .  "\n"; 
} 


// Call doIt() and pass our sample callback function's name. 
doIt('myCallback');
```

Displays: Data is: this is my data

Comment: Oh my god.  Is that the standard?  That's terrible!

Comment: There are a few other ways to do it as shown above. I really thought the same.

Comment: Wow, this adds some new twists to conventional programming.

Comment: @Nick Retallack, I don't see what is so horrible about it. For the languages I know of, such as JavaScript and C#, they all can structure their callback function in such pattern. Coming from JavaScirpt and C#, I am really not used to call_user_func(). It makes me feel like I have to adapt myself to PHP, instead of the other way around.

Comment: @Antony I was objecting to the fact that strings are function pointers in this language.  I posted that comment three years ago, so I'm pretty used to it by now, but I think PHP is the only language I know of (other than shell scripting) where this is the case.

Comment: @Antony I prefer to use the same syntax I use in javascript. So I don't even understand why people want to use `call_user_func()` When they have a syntax which enables them to dynamically call functions and make callbacks. I agree with you!

Answer (score 10):

One nifty trick that I've recently found is to use PHP's [`create_function()`](http://ca.php.net/create_function) to create an anonymous/lambda function for one-shot use. It's useful for PHP functions like `array_map()`, `preg_replace_callback()`, or `usort()` that use callbacks for custom processing. It looks pretty much like it does an `eval()` under the covers, but it's still a nice functional-style way to use PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately, the garbage collector doesn’t play very well with this construct producing potential memory leaks. 
If you’re out for performance, avoid create_function().

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer with PHP 7.4 version (arrow functions) and adding a warning about deprecated `create_function()`?

Answer (score 8):

well... with 5.3 on the horizon, all will be better, because with 5.3, we'll get closures and with them anonymous functions

http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures

Answer (score 8):

You will want to verify whatever your calling is valid. For example, in the case of a specific function, you will want to check and see if the function exists:

```
function doIt($callback) {
    if(function_exists($callback)) {
        $callback();
    } else {
        // some error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: What if callback is not a function, but an array holding object and method?

Comment: or rather `is_callable( $callback )`

Comment: Both are good suggestions - It will be necessary to check your own particular implementation of how you do a callback. I was hoping to warn against calling something that didn't exist causing a fatal. I made the answer more general

Answer (score 5):

`create_function` did not work for me inside a class. I had to use `call_user_func`.

```
<?php

class Dispatcher {
    //Added explicit callback declaration.
    var $callback;

    public function Dispatcher( $callback ){
         $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function asynchronous_method(){
       //do asynch stuff, like fwrite...then, fire callback.
       if ( isset( $this->callback ) ) {
            if (function_exists( $this->callback )) call_user_func( $this->callback, "File done!" );
        }
    }

}
```

Then, to use:

```
<?php 
include_once('Dispatcher.php');
$d = new Dispatcher( 'do_callback' );
$d->asynchronous_method();

function do_callback( $data ){
   print 'Data is: ' .  $data .  "\n";
}
?>
```

[Edit]
Added a missing parenthesis. 
Also, added the callback declaration, I prefer it that way.

Comment: Doesn't the Dispatcher class require an attribute for $this->callback = $callback to work?

Comment: @james poulson: PHP is a dynamic language, so it works. But I was being lazy. I usually do declare properties, makes everyones life easier. Your question made me look at that code again and spot a syntax error, thou. Thanks

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Thanks for the answer :) .

Comment: Woudn't it be safer to declare the do_callback function before creating the Dispatcher object and calling the async method?

Answer (score 4):

For those who don't care about breaking compatibility with PHP `< 5.4`, I'd suggest using type hinting to make a cleaner implementation.

```
function call_with_hello_and_append_world( callable $callback )
{
     // No need to check $closure because of the type hint
     return $callback( "hello" )."world";
}

function append_space( $string )
{
     return $string." ";
}

$output1 = call_with_hello_and_append_world( function( $string ) { return $string." "; } );
var_dump( $output1 ); // string(11) "hello world"

$output2 = call_with_hello_and_append_world( "append_space" );
var_dump( $output2 ); // string(11) "hello world"

$old_lambda = create_function( '$string', 'return $string." ";' );
$output3 = call_with_hello_and_append_world( $old_lambda );
var_dump( $output3 ); // string(11) "hello world"
```

Comment: **Warning** `create_function()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

I cringe every time I use `create_function()` in php.

Parameters are a coma separated string, the whole function body in a string... Argh... I think they could not have made it uglier even if they tried.

Unfortunately, it is the only choice when creating a named function is not worth the trouble.

Comment: And, of course, it's runtime string eval, so it doesn't get checked for valid syntax or anything else at compile time.

Comment: This answer has been outdated for the past 2 years. `create_function()` is now deprecated and should not be used.