# Dynamic Comparison Operators in PHP

Tags: php, variables, operators

Is it possible, in any way, to pass comparison operators as variables to a function? I am looking at producing some convenience functions, for example (and I know this won't work):

```
function isAnd($var, $value, $operator = '==')
{
    if(isset($var) && $var $operator $value)
        return true;
}

if(isAnd(1, 1, '===')) echo 'worked';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the point of such a function? The function call is much longer than the operation itself and I can't think of something useful to do with that.

Comment: You can if you use Scheme. It can be a very powerful pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about a small class:

```
class compare
{
  function is($op1,$op2,$c)
  {
     $meth = array('===' => 'type_equal', '<' => 'less_than');
     if($method = $meth[$c]) {
        return $this->$method($op1,$op2);
     }
     return null; // or throw excp.
  }
  function type_equal($op1,$op2)
  {
      return $op1 === $op2;
  }
  function less_than($op1,$op2)
  {
      return $op1 < $op2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think about using a class, too early in the morning maybe? Thanks.

Comment: Why does it need to be a class?

Comment: Before 5.3 this is the best choice, with namespaces and real callbacks other good solutions are possible. But a class is probably the simplest one.

Comment: It takes some time to understand your question. You are right, a class is not a required for this, but it is a common practice in PHP.

Comment: Very purposeful to make a comparison class! Solved my problem ! The question resembles my problem. Very handy ! +1

Answer (score 44):

You can also use [version_compare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function, as you can pass operator which will be used for comparison as third argument.

Comment: genius. +1 this is a pretty creative solution and works great for numeric comparisons.

Comment: Here is the example,  `if (version_compare(5.9, 6,'<='))   echo TRUE; // returns 1 `

Comment: I was actually creating a version compare function of my own because I didn't know PHP had this function, awesome!

Comment: watch out, that this won't work for any arbitrary string out there, only for numeric strings.

Comment: Excelent suggestion! Thanks

Answer (score 27):

How about this one?

```
function num_cond ($var1, $op, $var2) {

    switch ($op) {
        case "=":  return $var1 == $var2;
        case "!=": return $var1 != $var2;
        case ">=": return $var1 >= $var2;
        case "<=": return $var1 <= $var2;
        case ">":  return $var1 >  $var2;
        case "<":  return $var1 <  $var2;
    default:       return true;
    }   
}
```

Test:

```
$ops = array( "=", "!=", ">=", "<=", ">", "<" );
$v1 = 1; $v2 = 5;

foreach ($ops as $op) {
    if (num_cond($v1, $op, $v2)) echo "True  ($v1 $op $v2)\n"; else echo "False ($v1 $op $v2)\n";
}
```

Comment: you should include input/output in your test.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The top answer recommends a small class, but I like a trait.

```
trait DynamicComparisons{

private $operatorToMethodTranslation = [
    '=='  => 'equal',
    '===' => 'totallyEqual',
    '!='  => 'notEqual',
    '>'   => 'greaterThan',
    '<'   => 'lessThan',
];

protected function is($value_a, $operation, $value_b){

    if($method = $this->operatorToMethodTranslation[$operation]){
        return $this->$method($value_a, $value_b);
    }

    throw new \Exception('Unknown Dynamic Operator.');
}

private function equal($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a == $value_b;
}

private function totallyEqual($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a === $value_b;
}

private function notEqual($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a != $value_b;
}

private function greaterThan($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a > $value_b;
}

private function lessThan($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a < $value_b;
}

private function greaterThanOrEqual($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a >= $value_b;
}

private function lessThanOrEqual($value_a, $value_b){
    return $value_a <= $value_b;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bigger problem is that this function is pretty pointless. Let's replace that with a real (hypothetically working) example:

```
function isAnd($var, $value, $operator = '==') {
    return isset($var) && $var $operator $value;
}

isAnd($foo, 1, '===');
```

In this example `$foo` is not set. You'll get an error because you're trying to pass a non-existent variable (`$foo`) to a function (`isAnd`). So, you will need to test `$foo` for `isset` *before* calling `isAnd`:

```
isset($foo) && isAnd($foo, 1, '===');
```

So, any variable that ever enters the `isAnd` function is definitely set. You don't need to test for it inside the function. So the whole exercise is pretty pointless.

What may be confusing is that `isset()` and `empty()` don't have this limitation, i.e. you can pass a non-existent variable to them without error. The thing is though, these are not normal functions, they're special language constructs (that happen to look like functions; blame PHP). Unfortunately **you** can not make these kinds of constructs, parameters for your functions always need to exist.

You should just get used to writing `isset($foo) && $foo === 1`. With properly structured code, you can reduce this to a minimum by always declaring all variables you're going to use, which is good practice anyway.

For the dynamic operator... you'll need some form of `if ... else` somewhere to decide which operator to use anyway. Instead of setting the operator variable and then evaluating it, isn't it easier to do the evaluation right there?

Comment: Also see related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly/1960588#1960588

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely insist you can use eval.

```
if(isset($var) && eval("return \$var $operator \$value"))
    return true;
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: +1 - but some explanation of why you don't recommend it may be of value to the readers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution which should work for almost all the operators

Eg.

```
$b = 10;
$c = '+';
$p = $a . $c. $b; // Forming a String equation
$p = eval('return '.$p.';'); // Evaluating the Equation
echo $p;
```

Output:

```
15
```

Another example with comparison operator:

```
$b = 10;
$c = '==';
$p = $a . $c. $b;
$p = eval('return '.$p.';');
echo $p;
```

Output:

```
false
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Krelin suggests you could use eval - but that potentially enables a lot of code injection attacks.

You can't substitute a variable for an operator - but you can substitute a variable for a function:

```
function is_equal($a, $b) {
  return $a==$b;
} 
function is_same($a, $b) {
  return $a===$b;
}
function is_greater_than($a, $b)
....

$compare='is_equal';
if ($compare($a, $b)) {
   ....
```

C.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible and since there is no reference about callback on operators in PHP documentation,
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

instead of using eval, I would redefine each operators in global functions and use php callbacks
[How do I implement a callback in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 4;
eval('$condition=($a == 4)?true:false;'); 
if($condition){ echo "Yes"; }else{ echo "No"; }
```

Comment: Manoj Kumar, would you like to improve your question by augmenting it with some explanation? That would improve your chances for upvotes and at the same time help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is nothing but an unpaid code writing service.

Comment: In the explanation it would be especially helpful if you could explain the difference to the answer provided by Akshay Khale. I do not see a functional difference other than that there **is** an explanation and a more self-explanatory and convincing example which more obviously demonstrates the separation of the operator from the expression than in your code.

Answer (score -3):

No, it's impossible.
You can use conditional operators instead, but it will be **much,much better** if you redesign your application to make such a dynamic comparison unnecessary.