# Can I use operator in variable

Tags: php, operator-keyword, operands

Can I write code like below in php?

```
$operator = ">=90";
$val = 100;
if($val.$operator){
echo "Correct!";
}
```

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919190/dynamic-comparison-operators-in-php). It's not a strict duplicate (as the code you've shown is about evaluating expressions, and not just operators), but it might be worth taking a look over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function. Though, I would say you should look into [closures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) and even [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).

```php
$operator = fn($x) => $x >= 90;
$val = 100;
if($operator($val)){
    echo "Correct!";
}
```

Comment: Here you have declared '>=90' manually, but I have variable which stores the '>=90' string. Above code will not work in my case.

Comment: Read the link I provided about eval. Not sure what you are doing but I promise your are over complicating it. Explode the string if it is [dynamic and use a switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919190/dynamic-comparison-operators-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1). @AmolBorse