# How to access an argument of the "parent" function?

Tags: php, functional-programming, callback, global-variables

For example I have the following code:

```
function a($param)
{
  function b()
  {
    echo $param;
  }
  b();
}
a("Hello World!");
```

That throws an E_NOTICE error because $param is of course undefined (in b()).

I cannot pass $param to b() because b() should be a callback function of preg_replace_callback().
So I had the idea to save $param in $GLOBALS.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: FYI, `b` would be called a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) if it has access to `$param`.

Comment: @delnan: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: @Felix Kling: None, why are you asking? Closures are a language-agnostic concept.

Comment: @delnan: Oh sorry, I actually wanted to ask the OP ;)

Comment: OP? I have PHP 5.3.1 on XAMPP.

Comment: @Ondrej Slinták: Three persons have already noticed that! I know ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3, you could use [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with `use` keyword instead:

```
<?php
function a($param)
{
  $b = function() use ($param)
  {
    echo $param;
  };

  $b();
}
a("Hello World!");
```

Comment: I'd never seen this functionality before. +1 for teaching me something new here.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, since this was tagged *functional-programming*: in most functional programming languages, you would just refer to `param`, and it would be in scope, no problem. It's called lexical scoping, or sometimes block scoping.

It's typically languages without explicit variable declarations (eg "assign to define") that make it complicated and/or broken. And Java, which makes you mark such variables `final`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using objects here.

```
Class a {
    private $param;
    private static $instance;

    public function __construct($param){
        $this->param = $param;
        self::$instance = $this;
    }

    public function getParam(){
        return $this->param;
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        return self::$instance;
    }

}

function b(){
    echo a::getParam();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of each function lonely, and call the second function from the first function passing parameters.

It do your code more clear because each function do a single set of operations.

```
<?php
function a($param)
{
  b($param);
}
function b($param)
{
    echo $param;
}
a("Hello World!");
?>
```

Comment: But I want to use b() as a callback function of preg_replace_callback.
So with your solution I have to make $param globally available.

Comment: Maybe these links help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php] and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016264/php-callback-functions]

Comment: Maybe you must consider other alternatives since the solution above by Ondrej Slinták only works in PHP 5.3. In PHP 5.2 it returns parse error in line 4.

Comment: Yes, but the script I build only minimizes my own scripts (so 5.3.1).
But how would look an alternative with preg_replace_callback? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Before PHP 5.3 create_function() was used. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php