# Adding object to array, displays a count of 0

Tags: php, arrays, scope

Here's the code I'm running.

Basically I scrape data, and place them into simple POCO classes. At the end of the loop I want to add the `$newItem` object to the `$parsedItems` array. I'm new to PHP, can this be a scoping issue?

```
<h1>Scraper Noticias</h1>

<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

class News {
    var $image;
    var $fechanoticia;
    var $title;
    var $description;
    var $sourceurl;

    function get_image( ) {
        return $this->image;
    }

    function set_image ($new_image) {
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    function get_fechanoticia( ) {
        return $this->fechanoticia;
    }

    function set_fechanoticia ($new_fechanoticia) {
        $this->fechanoticia = $new_fechanoticia;
    }

    function get_title( ) {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function set_title ($new_title) {
        $this->title = $new_title;
    }

    function get_description( ) {
        return $this->description;
    }

    function set_description ($new_description) {
        $this->description = $new_description;
    }

    function get_sourceurl( ) {
        return $this->sourceurl;
    }

    function set_sourceurl ($new_sourceurl) {
        $this->sourceurl = $new_sourceurl;
    }
}

// Create DOM from URL or file
$initialPage = file_get_html('http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml');


// Declare variable to hold all parsed news items.
$parsedNews = array();

// Since the University blog page has 262 pages, we'll iterate through that.
for ($i = 2; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $url = "http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml?AA_SL_Session=34499aef1fc7a296fb666dcc7b9d8d05&scrl=1&scr_scr_Go=" . $i;
    $page = file_get_html($url);
    parse_page_for_news($page);
}

echo "<h1>Final Count:" . count($parsedNews) . "</h1>";

// Function receives an HTML Dom object, and the library works against that single HTML object.
function parse_page_for_news ($page) {

    foreach($page->find('#cont2 p') as $element) {

        $newItem = new News;

        // Parse the news item's thumbnail image.
        foreach ($element->find('img') as $image) {
            $newItem->set_image($image->src);
            //echo $newItem->get_image() . "<br />";
        }

        // Parse the news item's post date.
        foreach ($element->find('span.fechanoticia') as $fecha) {
            $newItem->set_fechanoticia($fecha->innertext);
            //echo $newItem->get_fechanoticia() . "<br />";
        }

        // Parse the news item's title.
        foreach ($element->find('a') as $title) {
            $newItem->set_title($title->innertext);
            //echo $newItem->get_title() . "<br />";
        }

        // Parse the news item's source URL link.
        foreach ($element->find('a') as $sourceurl) {
            $newItem->set_sourceurl("http://www.uvm.cl/" . $sourceurl->href);
        }

        // Parse the news items' description text.
        foreach ($element->find('a') as $link) {
            $link->outertext = '';
        }

        foreach ($element->find('span') as $link) {
            $link->outertext = '';
        }

        foreach ($element->find('img') as $link) {
            $link->outertext = '';
        }

        $newItem->set_description($element->innertext);

        // Add the newly formed NewsItem to the $parsedNews object.
        $parsedNews[] = $newItem;

        print_r($newItem);
        echo "<br /><br /><br />";

    }
} 

?>
```

In my current understanding of the language, since the `$parsedItems` object is declared outside of the function, shouldn't it correctly be added?

Why would my count() call return 0, as if it had no objects in it?

Comment: You probably mean `$parsedNews`. There's no `$parsedItems` in your code.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to manually write setters and getters if you're only using them as POCO-ish properties.  PHP has what are known as 'magic methods' that dynamically intercept when someone is trying to access object code.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550550/dumb-experiement-creating-c-esque-properties-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you could just add

```
global $parsedNews
```

inside you function declaration.  I would think it better coding practice to pass the item to the function by reference if you need to be able to modify it and have the modified value reflected in global scope.  So you could simply change you function signature to this

```
function parse_page_for_news ($page, &$parsedNews)
```

Comment: Thanks, both options worked. In this case, I'll go with passing the array as a function parameter instead of a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, don't use global variables.

Comment: Global variables, bad. Learning how to code correctly, priceless.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed a scoping issue. This will not work:

```
$foo= array();

function bar()
{
    $foo[] = 'baz';
}

bar();
var_dump($foo); // will output an empty array
```

What you want to do is the following:

```
$parsedNews = array();

// loop through the items as you are doing now
for ($i = 2; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $url = "http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml?AA_SL_Session=34499aef1fc7a296fb666dcc7b9d8d05&scrl=1&scr_scr_Go=" . $i;
    $page = file_get_html($url);
    $newItems = parse_page_for_news($page);

    $parsedNews = array_merge($parsedNews, $newItems);
}
```

And have the `parse_page_for_news` function return the `parsedNews` after the loop is finished:

```
return $parsedNews;
```

Please never ever use the `global` keyword and please don't pass by reference unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 3):

No. You're misunderstanding the concept of **[Variable Scope](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**.

Consider the following:

```
$foo = "bar";

function change_foo($new_foo) {
    $foo = $new_foo;
}

change_foo("New Foo!");
echo $foo;
```

The output in this case, would still be `"bar"`. That's because the `$foo` inside of `change_foo()` is contained inside of the *function scope*.

If we were to, however, do something like this (the proper way):

```
$foo = "bar";

function change_foo($new_foo) {
    $foo = $new_foo;
    return $foo;
}

$foo = change_foo("New Foo!");
echo $foo;
```

The result would be indeed `New Foo!`.

Another (less recommended) way of doing this, is the following:

```
$foo = "bar";

function change_foo(&$old_foo, $new_foo) {
    $old_foo = $new_foo;
}

change_foo($foo, "New Foo!");
echo $foo;
```

The reason this is not recommended, is because it's not obvious from the code that `$foo` is changed (of course, because of the proper name I gave the function, it seems obvious enough).

The worst way of doing this, is to move `$foo` into the global state.

```
$foo = "bar";

function change_foo($new_foo) {
    global $foo;
    $foo = $new_foo;
}

change_foo("New Foo!");
echo $foo;
```

By globalizing the `$foo` variable, anyone and everyone in the function can access and change it. If the function's name wasn't so obvious, we could never have known it changed the value of `$foo` at all!

Answer (score 2):

> In my current understanding of the language, since the $parsedItems object is declared outside of the function, shouldn't it correctly be added?

Nope, you'll need to pass it into the function, just like with C#.

Answer (score -6):

Your `News` object has no brackets. It should be a constructor, like this:

`$newItem = new News();`

Also, your `News` class needs a constructor. I am not sure if by not declaring one, it will be automatically given a default constructor (that is, without any arguments)

Comment: you don't need parenthesis if you are not going to pass parameters to a constructor function, or if a constructor function has default values it can use.

Comment: parenthesis are not strictly required for object instantiation

Comment: also, re: your edit - the class doesn't strictly *need* a constructor either.

Comment: I fixed the typos, but FYI this answer is not correct. Also, to address the question you raised in your "answer", classes without a constructor simply... don't have a constructor. There isn't a "default" one, nor does a class require one.