# php inline callback

Tags: php, callback, inline

A quick question.

Is it possible to declare the callback function inline, in php? For example,

```
array_filter($input_array, "function($item) { $item['state'] != 0 }")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, after php 5.3, you could use anonymous function.

```
array_filter($input_array, function($item) { return $item['state'] != 0; });
```

Comment: Not my case unfortunately.. 5.1 here :(

Comment: @jose Then you could use create_function http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: Note that each line of code inside the anonymous function needs to end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it calls [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
array_filter($input_array, function($item) { 
    return $item['state'] != 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_filter($input_array, function($item) { 
    return $item['state'] != 0;
});
```

This functionality is available from 5.3 or > version of php. In 5.4> version will support $this in inline Anonymous Functions

link for php callback >
[How do I implement a callback in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php)

Comment: this is an identical answer to the already accepted answer. Please avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

with create_function?
ex:

```
 $result = array_filter($array, create_function('$a','return preg_match("#\S#", $a);'));
```