# Calling function in another function

Tags: php, function

I have a function `printContent()` which prints the arguments and `logged()` which checks if the user is logged in.

My point is to do something like this:

```
logged("printContent('TITLE', 'CONTENT', 1)", 1);
```

It doesn't work. It should `printContent()` if user is not logged in, but nothing is happening. If I'll try changing `return()` into `print()` it prints the text "printContent(text...)".

Here are these two functions:

```
function logged($echo = 0, $logout = 0)
{    
        if($_SESSION['user']) 
        {
            if($echo)
            {
                if(!($logout)) return $echo;
                else return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
        else
        {  
            if($logout == 1) return $echo;
            else return false;
        }
}
function printContent($title, $content, $type = 0){
    if($type == 1){
        echo '<div class="right-box">';
        if($title) echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
        echo $content.'</div>';            
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="left-box">';
        if($title) echo '<h2>'.$title.'</h2>';
        echo '<div class="left-box-content">'.$content.'</div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `"printContent('TITLE', 'CONTENT', 1)"` is a string which you're passing into $echo.  Then you return $echo, which is just a string.  Your `if($echo)` check isn't doing what you want because $echo exists, but as a string.

Comment: Why on Earth should *strings* be evaluated as PHP code?

Comment: Note that `printContent()` isn't returning data: it is only echoing it. If you want to use the output from that function as input to another, you will need to `return` the data.

Comment: So your `logged()` function may return a ___string___ containing "printContent('TITLE', 'CONTENT', 1)"... why do you think a string should return the result of another function call just because it contains the name of another function?

Comment: Now just waiting to downvote the first answer that suggests using `eval()`

Comment: @MarkBaker: I'm happy to see that no one has done so yet! :-D

Comment: Thought about it just to see how many downvotes one can acquire in a short period of time

Answer (score 4):

> It should printContent() if user is not logged in

You can try

```
if(!logged())
{
printContent('TITLE', 'CONTENT', 1);
}
```

Comment: Of course...why complicated with callback if you can have it simple with if. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `logged()` function is too complicated; the `$echo` and `$logout` parameters make the logic extremely hard to follow. You should simplify it to just this, doing one thing very well:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    return !empty($_SESSION['user']);
}
```

Then, the logic becomes quite simple afterwards:

```
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    printContent('title', 'content', 1);
}
```

**Play time**

Being fancy, you could do this since 5.3, though it's a very contrived example of what you could accomplish with anonymous functions:

```
function ifLoggedIn($loggedIn, $loggedOut)
{
    return empty($_SESSION['user']) ? $loggedIn() : $loggedOut();
}
```

The `$loggedIn` and `$loggedOut` parameters are the callback parameters and get executed from inside the function, based on whether the user is logged in or not. To use it:

```
ifLoggedIn(function() {
}, function() {
    printContent('TITLE', 'CONTENT', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is a callback.

If I understand you correctly, you wish printContent only to execute, if the user is logged in, correct?

You may want to check this question for further info: [How do I implement a callback in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to execute a plain string. Use

```
function1( function2() );
```

that is the same as

```
$tmp = function2();
function1($tmp);
```

Comment: Problem is, this will run `function2` *before* `function1` is ran, and that may not be what the OP wants.