# Callback in function (PHP) is not working

Tags: php, oop

When I execute following code I am getting this error. Why is that? What is the proper use of callbacks?

#### CODE (simplified)

```
class NODE {
  //...some other stuff
  function create($tags, $callback=false) {
    $temp = new NODE();
    //...code and stuff
    if($callback) $callback($temp); //fixed (from !$callback)
    return $this;
  }
}
$document = new NODE();
$document->create("<p>", function($parent) {
$parent->create("<i>");
});
```

#### ERROR

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in P:\htdocs\projects\nif\nif.php on line 36
```

Comment: Can you post your line 36 here. so we can know what is there that's causing the problem?

Comment: `if(!$callback) $callback($this);` it's this line.

Comment: `if(!$callback)` => you only attempt to call the callback when it's `false` (and hence no valid callback...) For safety, you might want to `if(is_callable($callback)) $callback($temp);`

Comment: You can't have such a thing in php. $callback($this) is wrong in syntax if it's false. you should use function pointers if you really want to do this!

Comment: @MiroMarkarian so there is no way to JS-like callbacks in PHP?

Comment: @AreWojciechowski: Not if your callbacks are `=== false` due to you explicitely preventing anything else from going through an if. Also, `Callable` was added in 5.1 and formally put in 5.3, so if you're running less than that, they won't work.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski Yes there is a way actually. See my answer.

Comment: People. If your answer is not an answer to the question, it **goes in the comments**.

Comment: problem solved. it was this stupid `!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$document->new NODE();
```

This is not valid syntax. The accepted format would be:

```
$document = new NODE();
```

In addition to this, if you use the unary operator (`!`) on a false, you get true. If you use it on a `Callable`, you get false. As such, `if (!$callback) $callback()` will throw the first error of your script.

As a side note, you are reinventing the wheel. I would strongly recommend you take a look at the `DOMDocument` family of classes, which are doing exactly what you are currently trying to implement, albeit with fewer callbacks.

Comment: oops, it should be `document = new NODE();`, fixing.

Comment: Yes, I know `DOMDocument` but i need to write my own library for few purposes.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski: What is your purpose? You are aware that you can extend `DOMDocument`, right? If that doesn't fit the bill, you can also write a `Mediator` or `Adaptor` for it to do what you want to do.

Comment: I can't use external libraries or rather - I don't want to.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski: Any better reason than "don't want to"?

Comment: +1 (and more if I could give it) for just `extend`ing DOMDocument.

Comment: 'external'? [You have to explicitly disable it during compile time to remove it from PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php).

Comment: @Wrikken by external I meant "written by me". it's for exercise.

Comment: Ah well, just make sure your exercise doesn't end up in production is my thought on the matter. At any rate, the comment about the `!` not supposed to be there holds true.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$callback) $callback($temp);
```

should probably be

```
if($callback) $callback($temp);
```

And the instanciation:

```
$document = new NODE();
```

Comment: You are right about him having the `if` backwards, you are _wrong_ about having to provide a string rather then a function.

Comment: Sorry, had the call_user_func function in mind when doing this.
Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$callback) $callback($temp);
```

If `$callback` is `false`, for sure you won't be able to call it as a callback.

Comment: `function create($tags, $callback=false) { ... }` $callback is false by default, if not defined by user. if is anything else - executes. right? (i'm not sure if it's good)

Answer (score 0):

My 2c here, type hinting may be good to use here as well.

Ex: `function create($tags, callable $callback = function())`

Answer (score -1):

To do such a thing in php you should use function pointers and tell php which function to execute.
Look at this code.

```
// This function uses a callback function.
function doIt($callback)
{
    $data = acquireData();
    $callback($data);
}


// This is a sample callback function for doIt().
function myCallback($data)
{
    echo 'Data is: ', $data, "\n";
}


// Call doIt() and pass our sample callback function's name.
doIt('myCallback');
```

So as you seen you can only pass the name to the function and you should predefine the function..

Similar question: [How do I implement a callback in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php)

Comment: Completely off-topic and dangerous malpractice. By doing this, you are polluting the global namespace and forcing PHP to do a hash lookup on explicit name, something you would not have to do otherwise (passing a `Callable` would be one of them).

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I'm just trying to give the OP what he wants. and this is not off-topic. see the comments in the OP and you will see why I posted this answer. and stop down-voting to get your answer up.

Comment: His question was about the callback not working, not about creating a **doIt** function. His way of doing it is miles better than yours - he passes a function pointer/`Callable`, you pass a string reference (= significantly more memory, causes two PHP internal lookups, causes a below-the-bonnet `call_user_func` call). ***THIS*** is why you got a downvote - I don't have a care in the world about my answer. What I care about is not having OT (and blatantly incorrect) answers on a question.

Comment: And just to add water to the mill, this "method" which you copy-pasted from another question dates back from 12/08, when PHP **4** was the de-facto standard. That version of PHP did not have `Callable`. It's 5 years in the future now, and function pointers can be passed to functions.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld mate calm down. I didn't say I wrote the code. Did I? There is no need to "add water to the mill". I just posted my answer. either the best solution or the worst, this is my answer. You could simply comment saying this is not a good way to do it. instead of wowing about this being OT when it's actually A WORKING SOLUTION.

Comment: Miro: I said exactly that in my first comment. You're the one who went personal, "mate". I (rightfully) called your method a dangerous malpractice and explained exactly why it was. You immediately went *ad hominem*.