# Dynamic php function

Tags: php

How can we declare the function name dynamically?

For example :

```
$function = 'test'
public $function(){

}
```

Comment: Why should you be interested in the _name_ of a dynamic function? That makes no sense, since you never call it my its name. The example you give does _not_ attempt to define a dynamic function at all, but an ordinary global function.

Comment: Call a function from a variable may be.

Comment: @SougataBose For that you want to store a dynamic function ("lambda function") inside a variable. That does not change the _name_ of a function, but only it's scope.

Comment: i am interested to dynamic function , because i have to generate relation functions in yii2 model , these functoins change whene the model change .
So it should be dynamic.
Please read my post here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693837/advanced-yii2-application-function-to-generate-relation-model-dynamically-with

Comment: @arkascha, I meant - `function a() {echo 'hi';}; $a = 'a'; $a();`

Comment: @SougataBose Sure, I understood that. But still that does _not_ change the functions name as the OP asks.

Comment: Yes that does not. I am just sure why OP want to do that. I was just wandering. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523807/3887342

```
function doIt($callback) { $callback(); }

doIt(function() {
    // this will be done
});
```

Comment: And what is the purpose of this syntax artistic? Why not simply do what will be done?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a function with a variable but arbitrary name like this is not possible without getting your hands dirty with eval() or include().

I think based on what you're trying to do, you'll want to store an anonymous function in that variable instead (use create_function() if you're not on PHP 5.3+):

```
$variableA = function() {
    // Do stuff
};
```

You can still call it as you would any [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), like so:

```
$variableA();
```